# Forecasting using PC-VAR

Tags: time-series, forecasting, pca, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I am trying to forecast an index by using a PC-VAR. When performing the PCA, can I exclude the response variable from the dataset and find the PCs and later build a VAR with the response variable and selected PC’s which explain a descent amount of the variation (say 2 PCs).

Comment: That should be doable.

Comment: @RichardHardly thank you professor! In the proposed PC-VAR by Claudio Morana(2012)  it mentions they have used dynamic regression using a subset of principal components  . Is it the same regression which we use on time series such as OLS or something different?

Comment: Perhaps not. One needs to read the paper to know what exactly is meant by *dynamic regression*. It is a term with many definitions.

Comment: @RichardHardy This is the link to the paper. I greatly appreciate it if you could let me know what is meant here by the term  _dynamic regression_ . [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228163671_PC-VAR_Estimation_of_Vector_Autoregressive_Models)

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time to go through it. Perhaps someone else will, though.